# Is there any way to write RSpec test cases that would test directory or file presence

Tags: rspec, sinatra, rspec3

I have working project in Sinatra framework for which I have to write RSpec test cases. Herein we pass an argument to a method which then generates a folder with a file in it. Since I am very new to RSpec I don't know how I can test whether the folder and the file exist in the given path. From a lot of googling I did came across Aruba which is intended for same purpose but all it does creates the directory structure in its tmp folder and then test for the presence which I fill is not a valid way to do this. All I want for my test cases is to scan through my existing directory path which I have provided, that is outside of my project folder wherein they are actually created and run the test. Please correct me if this is not possible or even remotely doesn't make sense. Possible workarounds are welcome. Thank you. Oh and just a small mention, there are no controllers or an UI.

Comment: Are you looking for `expect(File.exist?(path)).to be true` or something else?

Comment: No. I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why? What does it say?